# apt vs apt-get error code

Tags: linux, apt, error-handling

Strange thing I have here, when `apt` is locked by something. Respectively, the error codes don't match up. `apt update` seems to always return success `0`, whereas `apt-get update` returns a proper error code.

```
vlastimil@vb-nb-mint ~/Development/bash $ sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

vlastimil@vb-nb-mint ~/Development/bash $ echo $?
100

vlastimil@vb-nb-mint ~/Development/bash $ sudo apt update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

vlastimil@vb-nb-mint ~/Development/bash $ echo $?
0
```

`apt`'s location:

```
vlastimil@vb-nb-mint ~/Development/bash $ which apt
/usr/local/bin/apt
```

`apt`'s version:

```
vlastimil@vb-nb-mint ~/Development/bash $ apt-show-versions apt
apt:amd64/xenial-updates 1.2.12~ubuntu16.04.1 uptodate
```

I originally wanted to use `apt` for the manual upgrade script, but this changes the situation. Does someone understand error codes and such in order to help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently intentional, see [#778357](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=778357): an exit code of 0 indicates success or a transient error, anything else indicates a permanent error.

As indicated in the `apt` manual page though:

> **SCRIPT USAGE AND DIFFERENCES FROM OTHER APT TOOLS**
>
> The `apt(8)` commandline is designed as an end-user tool and it may change behavior between versions. While it tries not
>          to break backward compatibility this is not guaranteed either if a change seems beneficial for interactive use.
>
> All features of `apt(8)` are available in dedicated APT tools like `apt-get(8)` and `apt-cache(8)` as well.  `apt(8)` just
>          changes the default value of some options (see `apt.conf(5)` and specifically the Binary scope). So you should prefer
>          using these commands (potentially with some additional options enabled) in your scripts as they keep backward
>          compatibility as much as possible.

So you shouldn't use `apt` in scripts.

(It's odd that you have `apt` in `/usr/local/bin`; given that you have an up-to-date `apt` package installed, you probably have it in `/usr/bin` too!)